# How do I get this PHP cURL Get working for this URL

Tags: php, curl, get

I have this URL as a GET
https://api-gametroove.eeposit.com/auth/gameland_subscription_status/

Need to send it like this
https://api-gametroove.eeposit.com/auth/gameland_subscription_status/270830000000

with 270830000000 being the mobile number.

The response is supposed to be
{
"success": true,
"message": "Subscription status checked successfully.",
"params": {
"subscriptStatus": true
}
}

I am using the following code, but don't get any response back.

function subscriber($msisdn){

```
$URL = "https://api-gametroove.eeposit.com/auth/gameland_subscription_status/".$msisdn; 

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;  
}

subscriber('2773000000');
```

If I do above nothing is returned. How can I check if any errors or should I use another
method to do the GET for thsi URL?

Comment: That is totally ok. Are you sure no key or auth is neccessary? Does it need be POST?

Comment: The response is supposed to be in this format if the number exist in the database but for above example or any made up number success will be false and the rest will show the false statements. { "success": true, "message": "Subscription status checked successfully.", "params": { "subscriptStatus": true } } I'm not sure if what I have is working because I'm not getting anything back.

Comment: according to the dev no auth or key required

Comment: I think it might be related to missing SSL certifcate verification, you can check answer at [getimagesize() is not working with PNG images having HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638748/getimagesize-is-not-working-with-png-images-having-https/36640201#36640201)

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE and show the verbose log: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh);
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
``` and show the verbose log

Comment: Can someone please test my script to see if it actually is a curl get that can be done on this URL or should I use another method. I'm not getting any data even if I add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, false);